# cassandra: get columns of a wide row in reverse order with some filtering

Tags: cassandra, time-series, cql3, cqlsh

I understand that cassandra does not support order by with secondary indexes but I really do not want order by feature. All I want is an ability to get columns in ascending or descending order as stored in column family since cassandra already sorts column names.

I would like to model time series data in cassandra as wide rows. I need to access this data in ascending or descending order. I would also like to create couple of secondary indexes to do select queries. So my column family at_data would look something like,

```
create table at_data (acct_bucket_id text,
             ... ts varint,
             ... status int,
             ... side int,
             ... instrument_id varint,
             ... data text,
             ... PRIMARY KEY (acct_bucket_id, ts, status, side, instrument_id)
             ... ) with comment = 'audit data';
```

If I add data to this column family.

```
insert into at_data (acct_bucket_id, ts, status, side, instrument_id, data) values ('1:1', 1, 1, 1, 1, 'order 1');
insert into at_data (acct_bucket_id, ts, status, side, instrument_id, data) values ('1:1', 2, 1, 1, 1, 'order 2');
insert into at_data (acct_bucket_id, ts, status, side, instrument_id, data) values ('1:1', 3, 2, 1, 1, 'order 3');
```

and would like to get 'data' in descending order where status matches 1. So I created query,
select * from at_data where acct_bucket_id='1:1' and status=1 order by ts desc;

and got error,
Bad Request: ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks,
Shridhar

Answer (score 1):

You can do `select * from at_data where acct_bucket_id = '1:1' and ts = 1 and status = 1 order by ts desc;` You can't skip `ts` in your query, because it goes before `status` in primary key. And you can't order by `status` because order by accepts only second key of the primary key.

You can change your primary key to `PRIMARY_KEY (acct_bucket_id, status, ts, side, instrument_id)` - put `status` before `ts`. In this case you can do `select * from at_data where acct_bucket_id='1:1' and status = 1 order by status desc;`

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I cannot switch ts and status since I want columns to be sorted by time stamp. For the queries like, give me last 100 columns where status is 1, I would not know timestamp(ts) of last column. Also query you suggested(select * from at_data where acct_bucket_id = '1:1' and ts = 1 and status = 1 order by ts desc;) wouldn't work for same reason as my example query didn't work.

Comment: `select * from at_data where acct_bucket_id = '1:1' and status = 1 order by status desc limit 100;`
This query will give you last 100 rows and it will be sorted by ts in descending order.

Comment: You don't need to order by ts. Cassandra has datamodel that is Map<PartitionKey, SortedMap<ColumnName, Data>>. When you create PRIMARY KEY (acct_bucket_id, status, ts, side, instrument_id), acct_bucket_id becomes your PartitionKey and the rest form composite ColumnName in SortedMap. When in your query you add order by status desc - it means order ColumnName with all it columns including ts

Comment: I understand that I do not need to order by ts since column names are sorted in a row. As my example suggests, I created a table, created secondary index on status and ran query 'select * from at_data where acct_bucket_id = '1:1' and status = 1 order by ts desc limit 100;'. cqlsh gives me error, Bad Request: ORDER BY with 2ndary indexes is not supported. I did NOT create secondary index on 'ts'. I just created secondary index on 'status'.